# What is Eragon's True Name?

Tags: inheritance-cycle

In book 4 of the Inheritance Cycle

> Eragon finds his true name, but does the book ever tell the actual name itself?

Comment: [**Christopher Paolini** - "*Eragon's true name is Hiro Gary-Stu Protagonist the XXIII*"](https://twitter.com/paolini/status/583293560411201536)

Comment: Are *any* true names ever revealed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### This is intentionally never revealed and likely doesn't even exist.

> *In regard to Eragon’s true name, I chose not to reveal it because those words are words of magic. I felt that giving them to readers would spoil some of the mystery and power they hold. You could say the whole Inheritance Cycle encompasses Eragon’s true name. But its short form is a secret between Eragon, Saphira, Glaedr, and Arya.*
>
> [source](https://www.paolini.net/2014/10/06/qas-burning-questions/)